# He promised him a noble title if Andalucia was/were conquered

Tags: grammar, subjunctive-mood

I want to choose "were" because Andalucia hasn't been conquered yet - it's a hypothetical scenario calling for subjunctive. However, I see that "promised" is in past tense. If the sentence were: "He would promise him a noble title if Andalucia was/were conquered", then it would definitely be "were".

I just want to confirm if the correct answer is "were" (and in the scenario that "was" is the correct answer, why subjunctive couldn't be applied).

Comment: Certainly *El rey le prometió un título de nobleza una vez que toda Andalucía **fuera** conquistada* takes the subjunctive, but English may not be quite so clear-cut here. :)

Comment: I got the sentence from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pvD0VqF9saY). Timestamp 9:14.

Comment: Oh I see. Yes, that’s just backshifting the indicative, so not subjunctive.

Comment: You may be looking for "He promised him a noble title when Andalucia should be conquered".  The implication is that the timing is uncertain, but the eventual change from counter-factual to reality is certain.